# OpenEdge Progress-4GL development: how to know from an error message the procedure I'm running?

Tags: debugging, openedge, progress-4gl, callstack

As stated in previous questions, I'm quite new at Progress-4GL development.

I've just created a windows `(*.w file)`, together with a procedure file `(*.p file)`, which are based on an include file `(*.i file)`.

I've done something wrong and I get an error message, copy-paste reveals the following:

```
---------------------------
Fout
---------------------------
** Begin positie voor SUBSTRING, OVERLAY, enz. moet 1 of groter zijn. (82)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

As you can see, this is the Dutch translation of error 82:

```
** Starting position for SUBSTRING, OVERLAY, etc. must be 1 or greater. (82)

The SUBSTRING, OVERLAY, etc, functions require that the start position (second argument) be greater than or equal to 1. 
P
```

I'd like to know which procedure/function is launching this error message. I'm working with the AppBuilder release 11.6 and the corresponding procedure editor, so the debugging possibilities are very limited. One thing I'm thinking of, is taking a dump of the Windows process, in order to determine the call stack, but I'm not sure how to do this. I also tried using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) and check the stack of the individual stacks of the threads inside the "procwin32.exe" process, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

By the way, I'm regularly adding message boxes to my code, which look as follows (just an example):

```
MESSAGE "begin procedure combobox-value-changed" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

As you see, the name of the procedure is hardcoded, while in other programming languages (like C++) the procedure/function name can be shown as follows:

```
OUTPUT("begin procedure %s", __FUNCTION__);
```

Next to `__FUNCTION__`, C++ also knows `__FILE__` (for filename) and `__LINE__` (for line number).
Do such predefined values also exist in Progress 4GL, preferably release 11.6 or previous?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As ABL code is not compiled into Windows byte-code a windows debugger will not be really helpful.

You should start by adding the -debugalert startup parameter to prowin/prowin32.exe. Or add this

```
ASSIGN SESSION:DEBUG-ALERT = TRUE .
```

That will add a HELP button to all (error) messages which will open a dialog with the ABL stack trace.

As you'Re using include files, be aware that the line numbers referenced in the stack-trace are based on the debug listing, not the actual source code. So execute

```
COMPILE myfile.w DEBUG-LIST c:\temp\myfile.debuglist .
```

to receive the debug-listing file with the correct line numbers.

Are you aware of the visual debugger that's available for the AVM? https://docs.progress.com/de-DE/bundle/openedge-abl-troubleshoot-applications-117/page/Introduction.html

```
%DLC%\bin\proDebugger.bat
```

Or the Compile -> Debug menu in the AppBuilder.

It looks a bit antique, but usually does it's job.

Debugging needs to be enabled as an Administrator in proenv:

```
prodebugenable -enable-all
```

Of course the grass is greener when you switch to Progress Developer Studio as your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the second part of your question. See the [PROGRAM-NAME](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/PROGRAM-NAME-function.html) function.

```
message
  program-name(1) skip
  program-name(2)
  .
```

Additionally see the [{} preprocessor name reference](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-reference-117/page/Preprocessor-name-reference.html).

`message 'file: {&file-name} line: {&line-number}'.`

Comment: I already had a look at the "program-name()" function. Unfortunately, this shows the name of the program (*.w file), but not the procedure (like the name of the procedure in the *.p file).

Comment: It shows internal procedure space file - see https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=5fe9f5b40bb85467879db1a0